# How to get a textfield value from a ionic2 framework alert box?

Tags: angular, ionic2

How do I get the textfield value from a ionic2 framework alert box?

#### alert.html

```
 <ion-item ('click')="enterPwd();">Admin</ion-item>
```

#### alert.ts

```
enterPwd() { 
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Enter 4 digit PIN',
        inputs: [{name:'PIN',placeholder:'pin',type:'password'}],
        buttons: [{
            text:'Done',
            type:'button-positive',
            handler: data => {
                console.log('Done clicked');
                //pin entered should be displayed in console.. 
            }
        }]
    });
    alert.present();
}
```

When an item is clicked, `enterPwd` will be called, showing the alert. When the user enters their PIN, I wish it to display in the console.

Comment: you mean within the handler?

Comment: reformat, reword, make legible

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the name of the text input and access with it.
Your inputs is:

```
`inputs:[{name:'PIN',placeholder:'pin',type:'password'}`],
```

In your handler,

```
handler: data => {
                console.log('Done clicked');
               //TO DISPLAY PIN
                console.log(data['PIN']); 
                }
```